# More Efficient Way to Avoid Multiple Calculations?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a lot of these chains in my sheet. Is there a more efficient way than what I am doing?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sm1WLL6CJHckeUE1eyZQSG4CRb35UVxOb1Ymwtf6Yj8/edit?usp=sharing

```
=$A$2+5
=$A$2+15
=$A$2+20
```

etc.

It there a single formula or more efficient one that may reduce calculation time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A1:A20)*5+A2)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I appologize.  I am struggling with how to apply this.  Does A1 have to be the top value of where the array formula starts and does this need to be dragged down the column?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Just figured it out.  THAT IS REALLY COOL. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot figure out how to show that you answered my question.