# More Efficient Way to Avoid Multiple Calculations #2?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Here is a more difficult version of another post I made earlier today.
[More Efficient Way to Avoid Multiple Calculations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979532/more-efficient-way-to-avoid-multiple-calculations)
  I have a lot of these chains in my sheet. Is there a more efficient way than what I am doing?

Here is an example post of more difficult formula needed.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qejqo0WzMYa5K7YCnovW-7ki97DCX2h6gGA7LE7Eeh8/edit?usp=sharing

```
=INDIRECT("Data!E"&(K8-1))
=INDIRECT("Data!E"&(K9-1))
=INDIRECT("Data!E"&(K10-1))
```

etc.

Can I modify this to work?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A1:A20)*????)
```

It there a single formula or more efficient one that may reduce calculation time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K8:K-1, {ROW(A:A), Data!E:E}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I have been having trouble with these array formulas sometimes hesitating to calculate for lack of better terms.  The data in sheet data of my live project imports a new row and copies down every minute.  Processing time has been average of only 7 seconds to calculate everything when the trigger runs this every minute, but sometimes like today it is running over 30 seconds every minute and I will get a warning soon from Google that I am using to many resources.  I am seeing that while it is lagging behind, this along with other array formulas are taking very long.Any suggestions at all please?

Comment: Before changing these to array formulas processing time was about 9 or 10 seconds average every minute, but I never had periods of time that would run 30 - 40 seconds.  Have you heard of this happening?

Comment: well, arrayformulas calculate also empty rows unless you specify they shouldn't. for example above formula could be written in superfast mode like: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("K8:K"&COUNTA(K8:K)+7)-1, {ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(Data!E1:E))), INDIRECT("Data!E1:E"&COUNTA(Data!E1:E))}, 2, 0)))` - which will exclude empty rows from being calculated. but ofc the "superfast" execution depends on actual input length. the rule stands: fewer rows to compute = faster the execution

Comment: Thanks!  Based on your idea of using INDIRECT(),   F7 changes are what changes column K and is zero most of the time so I will just use an IF true then use the INDIRECT which doesn't change.  =IF(F7=0,ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(AQ43:AQ79-1, {ROW(INDIRECT("Data!A13:A600")), INDIRECT("Data!E13:E600")}, 2, 0)),ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(AQ43:AQ79-1, {ROW(Data!A:A), Data!E:E}, 2, 0)))

Comment: Would you happen to know if it "(Data!A:A)" searches top to bottom?  If so, the lookup field is starting at the top down to a particular number so it would probably matter much if it is I am thinking?  Also, I have no empty rows. Thanks for taking my questions.

Comment: yes, A:A starts from A1 and ends with last cell in column A